# I cloned a repo using ssh, yet when im trying to push now im getting as public key denied warning

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I tried `ssh -T git@github.com` and was successfully authenticated.

this is the error I get when trying to push.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Use `ssh -Tv` to verify that you're authenticating as the desired user. Probably, you are using an ssh agent and you no longer have the key for the user that works in the agent, so ssh is moving on to the remaining keys, none of which work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your current account (`id -a` on Linux, or `set username` on Windows), from a Visual Studio Code shell.
Check also HOME (`echo $HOME` or `echo %HOME%`), since Git/SSH will look for your key in `~/.ssh`

Make sure you are pushing to your own repository (or fork that you own), and not to the remote upstream original repository (that you might not own or be a collaborator of): `git remote -v`

Comment: hey, so i checked the current account and the repo im pushing to and they all seem well, however when i check where the $HOME is, it returns the /users/myuser not the root (~) directory, could that be the issue?

Comment: ~ is synonymous to home

Comment: @whitebat199 Did you execute any command as root, or in a shell opened as root?

Comment: yes i executed the command as root. but again when i try to authenticate to github from the terminal it works fine, but when i try to push the code from vscode it gives the permission denied error, and i double checked where to im pushing.

Comment: @whitebat199 Don't execute anything as root. It won't access the same SSH keys.

Comment: I tried both ways and was authenticated from the terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244757/discussion-between-vonc-and-whitebat-199).